# "Provisional headers are shown" requisição lenta

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Quando eu faço uma requisição AJAX com `$.post` do jQuery, enquanto a requisição é feita o Chrome me exibe uma mensagem **Provisional headers are shown** e sinto que ele para a requisição enquanto exibe essa mensagem, assim demorando mais pra terminar a requisição

Alguém sabe como posso resolver? talvez dizer para o Chrome não me notificar mais sobre ela... sei que é por causa dos cabeçalhos mas estão todos normais e o sistema é fechado então não corre perigo.

Comment: Duas coisas pra você checar: 1) se tem alguma extensão do chrome bloqueando conteúdo (adblocks em geral), desative e faça novamente o teste. 2) certifique-se do ajax estar sendo feito pro mesmo dominio. (mesmo www.dominio.com e dominio.com sao coisas diferentes para um bom teste)

Comment: @Bacco sim, já verifiquei essas duas possibilidades e está tudo certo.

Answer (score 2):

Silvio, tudo bom? Tive um problema semelhante, acabei descobrindo que era realmente um problema na minha aplicação.

Trago dois links que me ajudaram a esclarecer mais sobre esse alerta do Chrome, podem ser úteis para você também:

[Possível erro de extensão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

[Issue aberta no projeto do Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294891)

Comment: Será que pode ser porque a identidade do site não está comprovada?

Comment: Então, depois que li mais sobre e presenciei alguns episódios semelhantes, percebi que é realmente o tipo de coisa que aparece só quando a requisição demora muito tempo pra ser respondida. Provavelmente é uma solução colocar cabeçalhos provisórios para respostas que sejam muito longas, ou demoradas. Uma boa dica que tirei disso para mim, que pode também ser útil para você é tentar rever sua requisição e o que ela trabalha. Provavelmente refatora-la pode ser uma boa opção.

Comment: Ah entendi, então você quer dizer que essa mensagem só aparece quando a requisição demora muito ao invés de ela causa a demora?

Comment: Exatamente Silvio! Eu acredito que essa seja uma conclusão bem sensata.